# how to start for-next-loop from central value out to extremes

Tags: python, r, for-loop, iterator, julia

For example, if one wants to iterate a for loop from 1 to 5, one should write like
`for i=1:1:5`. Let me use `Julialang` in my explanation. In this case, the index
starts from 1 to 5 whose step is 1. If I'd prefer to iterate from its central value
out to the extrema like `3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 5 -> 1`, I wonder
how I should implement. I can imagine that one should create some array.
But, I wonder how to assign the elements for this array.

Thanks in advance for kind suggestion.

Comment: In which language are you looking for an answer? Why have you tagged this `r`, `python`, `julia` ?

Comment: I prefer Julialang, but also I can convert the other two to Julia.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance of each element to the central value, then sort the array using that distance. e.g.

```
a = 1:5
for i in sortperm(abs.(a .- sum(a) / length(a)))
    println(a[i])
end
```

`sortperm` returns the sorted indices. Alternatively, you can create a sorted array.

```
a = 1:5
b = sort(a, by=x->abs(x-sum(a)/length(a)))
# now b is [3,2,4,1,5] for you to iterate
```

Comment: Note this is the *central value*, but despite the phrasing of the poster I think the real question is to iterate outward from the *central index*.

Comment: Concerning tholy's comment, do you mean the number of iteration (in this MWE case, this is 5) must be odd to coincide between central value and index?

Comment: If the goal is to iterate the indices (i.e. `a` is always a unit range starts from 1), there would be some more performant tricks. This snippet should still work though.